# Ceph set default stripe-count stripe-unit

Tags: openstack, ceph, cinder

Currently i have an OpenStack environment with Ceph as a backend storage driver for Cinder.

I have looked into cinder documentation and code and i could not find any values or options to set the default stripe_unit or stripe_count for rbd volumes.

The reason i want to do this is that i want to have my volumes striped.

Is it possible to set default stripe_count and stripe_unit in ceph.conf ?

i have tried to add the following to the [client] section in ceph.conf , but it did not work
rbd stripe-count N 
rbd stripe-unit  N

Any advise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to set these values in the ceph.conf file :
I also needed to enable some features for expirements and i needed to increase the object size as well, this is what order is.

```
rbd default features = 12
rbd default format = 2
rbd default stripe_count = 16
rbd default stripe_unit = 4194304
rbd default order = 23
```